# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'bgsegm

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting the following error: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'bgsegm'.

I am using Python 3.6 with OpenCV 3.6 on windows machine.
I tried using the pip install opencv-contrib-python command but still the problem remains same on my windows machine. This command helped be on Ubuntu system, but not on windows. I searched similar problems on stack but couldn't solve this issue. Can someone help me out on this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you included contrib modules in your OpenCV build?

Comment: @Mika72 Are you talking about `pip install opencv-contrib-python` ? If no, then can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 25):

You need to install the `contrib` dependencies to get this working as it isn't part of the standard build.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: I have already installed it.(I have mentioned this above as well.)But still the error is popping up.

Comment: Did you check `pip --version` to make sure it's using the correct python version?

Comment: In my understanding you have to compile cv2 contrib library (you can not use pip) in certain environments (e.g. in Raspberry Pi).

Comment: He was mentioning that he is using it on a windows system. I've tested it on a windows system, which works  completely fine.

Comment: I reinstalled opencv and it's working now. Thanks everyone

Comment: didn't solve my problem even after reinstalling the opencv

Comment: Works now. Had to use "python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python"

Comment: I had the same issue. I solved it by pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python and pip install it.

Answer (score 6):

Installing contrib dependencies will fix your problem:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Alternatively, you can use the newer `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()`, which is directly available in cv2:

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```

Comment: Switching to `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python3, write:

```
fgbg =cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() #For python3
```

And not:

```
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

Comment: `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() ` doesnt seem to work for python3

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this issue arises when someone tries to install multiple packages of OpenCV or even tries to install multiple packages of OpenCV in a different order.

If you read the official `opencv-contrib-python` [installation docs](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/) there is written that you only need to install one package of OpenCV.

For example, if you need a base OpenCV module with extra contrib modules, you just need to install `opencv-contrib-python` with the appropriate version you want:

```sh
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

And this will install both OpenCV and OpenCV contrib modules.

The reason for that is all the OpenCV modules use the same namespace which is `cv2` and do not use the plugin architecture. So, when you install the other module, it will rewrite the existing namespace with a new module library that is being installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3.4.2.16 Version of OpencV, you can try this version of OpencV

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

instead of

```
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

you need not use bgsegm .