# Python does not find bgsegm from cv2

Tags: python, opencv, conda, background-subtraction

I am trying to test some background subtraction methods (following the [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html)) but Python fails to find them.

Using Windows and Anaconda. I made sure to upgrade **opencv** through conda and ran 
the

> pip install opencv-contrib-python

command as recommended in another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674051/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-bgsegm).

Still, I get this:

```
(tracx) C:\Users\USER>python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 14:34:30) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG'
>>> quit()
```

Comment: were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking for `f = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()`.

The function currently resides within the `bgseg` (background segmentation) module.